# Create a new "Shell Tool" target in Xcode for the use of Google Test

Tags: c++, xcode6, googletest

I am trying to add [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) framework to my existing C++ project. And I am following their [XcodeGuide](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide). However, I cannot get over this following step.

> 3. Create a new "Shell Tool" target in your Xcode project called something like "UnitTests"

**So question: what is a shell tool target for a Xcode project. Is it still available in Xcode 6. If it is, where? If it is not, any workaround?**

Edit: I don't want to use [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html) because (a) it is not cross platform (b) it supports well for Obj-C but not so well for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project. On the creation dialog, select "Command Line Tool" as your project type. This is what is probably meant by "Shell Tool." It is available in Xcode 6.